# "Animosity" Vs "Feud"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

I cannot understand the difference between the two words "[feud](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/feud)" and "[animosity](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/animosity)".

The only thing that I can think of is that "animosity" has a strong anger, hatred and even sometimes hidden "vengeance" in it, while the word "feud" lacks all of these (at least to the extent of "animosity".)

This is why I'm not quite confident which word fits better in which case.

Let me bring up three separate scenarios. Please let me know which one fits in each case and why.

**Scenario 1:**

- > When parents separate, sorting out the arrangements for their children can become difficult, especially if there is ........ between them. [[Source]](https://www.clarionsolicitors.com/mobile/blog/making-child-arrangements-when-parents-separate)

  1. animosity
  2. a feud

**Scenario 2:**

- > Since a youth from the tribe A killed a girl from the tribe B, there is a strong hatred and ....... between the people of the two tribes. [Self-made]

  1. animosity
  2. a feud

**Scenario 3:**

- > There has always been a fear and ........ between the people of that country living abroad. They have never been able to believe and trust each other. This is why they have always tried to keep away from one another. [Self-made]

  1. animosity
  2. a feud

P.S. I think they both can be used in each case. The only difference which comes to my mind as I mentioned is that "animosity" carries a more serious hatred and vengeance feeling, while the word "feud" lacks it.

Comment: Animosity is a feeling or emotion; a feud is a dispute.

Comment: It doesn't answer this question @Michael Harvey. Hoever, thank you for the comment.

Comment: How does his comment not answer the question? A dispute is not an emotion.

Comment: @Micah Windsor I guess with your emphasis everything is getting clear in my mind. Then I think in all three cases of mine, "animosity" is the best choice. Do you confirm?

Comment: For 1 and 3, I suppose. For two, I would say "a feud", because that is a familiar context in which feuds often come up (tribal wars). Note that you don't need to say "a fear" in 3 or "a strong hatred" in 1. The article "a" is unneeded here and "hatred" is by definition strong.

Comment: But as you and Michael mentioned, "feud" is a dispute, not a "feeling / emotion". While in #2 we are talking about an emotion! How can you explain that so that I can figure that out?

Comment: Actually, yes. I take that back. It was the article "a" that made me choose "a feud", to be consistent. If we change "a strong hatred" to just "hatred", I would use "animosity".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Animosity**: a strong **feeling** of dislike or hatred. [(source)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/animosity)

**Feud**: a mutual **enmity** or **quarrel** that is often prolonged or inveterate. [(source)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feud)

---

To illustrate why your scenarios are not evidence to support there being no difference between definitions, let's imagine a new, slightly absurd scenario:

> *Two angry children stand on either side of an elephant. There is ___ between them.*

Animosity? Or an elephant?

This does not mean that *animosity* means *an elephant*. It also does not mean that there cannot be a sense in which these terms are equivalent (though there probably isn't).

Essentially, *animosity* and *feud* may be interchangeable in some contexts, but are not necessarily.

---

> *"You know sometimes words have two meanings..."* ~ Led Zeppelin, *Stairway to Heaven*

Answer (score 2):

Feud refers actions, not feelings.  Hence, it can be used to refer to people who snipe at each other whenever they meet, who refuse to speak to each other even though they literally live next door, who try to sabotage each other's social success, career, or relationship to the children, or who can't be trusted in the same room together for fear they would try to murder each other.

Animosity is the feelings that may (or may not) be behind the feud.